# Wordpress Tax Query Problem - How to query by taxonomy, specific parent AND child term?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Custom Post Type called 'references' with the taxonomy 'references-cats'. Parent and child terms are:

- social media
- corporate communications
- events
- competences

  - social media
  - events

Some of some of the Child Terms are **identical** with the Parent Terms. **I would like to query all posts of 'social media' (but only the children of 'competences') – is there an exact way to do that?**

```
<?php 

$tagz = get_the_title(); // single post title as we are on a single page

    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'references',
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array (
                'taxonomy' => 'references-cats',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $tagz, // single post title corresponds with term
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'references-cats',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'competences',
                'operator' => 'IN'
            )
        ),
        'showposts' => 7
    ) ); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Terms in WordPress have unique slugs, so it doesn't matter if you have 2 terms with the same names, they will have different slugs. So you don't need to query the references by both parent and child since you are anyway using the slug to make the tax query.

```
'tax_query' => array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'references-cats',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $slug
    )
)
```

The above piece of code is enough for the tax query, you should just use the proper slug for each taxonomy term in the $slug variable.

L.E.:

Matching your title with your term slug is not a good approach. You can achive what you want easily by creating a metabox on the page(with ACF of with custom code) where you select the category from which you want to display references on each specific page.

Comment: Sorry, this way the tax_query returns posts from Parent Term Social Media too. I would like to recieve only Posts from the Parent Term 'Competences' and there from the Child-Term 'Social Media'. But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: The parent term "social media" has a certain slug, probably 'social-media', while the child term "social media" has another slug, probably 'social-media-2' or 'social-media-competences'. You need to use the child term's slug in the query and you will only get the posts in the child term.

Comment: Now you bring me closer to my problem... : the tax_query takes place on a Single Page Template and I can only use the 'terms' => 'TERM NAME AS VARIABLE INSERTED HERE'. As I can't use the slug, is there a nother approach to check if the Term belongs to the Parent Term 'competences'?

Comment: I can't really understand why you can't use slug and you need to use the name, if you have access to the term name you should also have access to the term slug.

Comment: I added more code and two comments in the code above, maybee it makes it clear...

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

1. Query for all posts with parent taxonomy. competences
2. Then in while loop check if post have child taxonomy.

Example:

```
$args_query = array(
    'post_type' => array('references'),
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'references-cats',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array(PARENT-TAXONOMY-ID),
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args_query );

if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        if (has_term($tagz, 'references-cats')) {
            // have $tags
        }
    }
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also you can use below code instead of has_term()

```
if (is_object_in_term( $post->ID, $taxonomy, $term )) {
    // code
}
```